# Is there a way to chain a pd.cut FunctionTransformer in a sklearn Pipeline?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm working on making a DataFrame pre-processing pipeline using sklearn and chaining various types of pre-processing steps.

I wanted to chain a `SimpleImputer` transformer and a `FunctionTransformer` applying a `pd.qcut` (or `pd.cut`) but I keep getting the following error:

> ValueError: Input array must be 1 dimensional

Here's my code:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

class FeatureSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, features):
        self._features = features

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return X[self._features]

fare_transformer = Pipeline([
    ('fare_selector', FeatureSelector(['Fare'])),
    ('fare_imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('fare_bands', FunctionTransformer(func=pd.qcut, kw_args={'q': 5}))
])
```

The same happens if I simply chain the `FeatureSelector` transformer and the `FunctionTransformer` with `pd.qcut` and omit the `SimpleImputer`:

```
fare_transformer = Pipeline([
    ('fare_selector', FeatureSelector(['Fare'])),
    ('fare_bands', FunctionTransformer(func=pd.qcut, kw_args={'q': 5}))
])
```

I searched stackoverflow and google extensively but could not find a solution to this issue. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sklearn already has such a transformer, `KBinsDiscretizer` (to match `pd.qcut`, use `strategy='quantile'`).  It will differ primarily in how it `transform`s test data: the `FunctionTransformer` version will "refit" the quantiles, whereas the builtin `KBinsDiscretizer` will save the quantile statistics for binning test data.  As @m_power notes in a comment, they also differ near bin edges, as well as the format of the transformed data.

But to address the error specifically: it means your function `qcut` only applies to a 1D array, whereas `FunctionTransformer` sends the entire dataframe.  You can define a thin wrapper around `qcut` to make this work, like

```py
def frame_qcut(X, y=None, q=10):
    return X.apply(pd.qcut, axis=0, q=q)
```

(That's assuming you'll get a dataframe in.)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. By selecting the column 'Fare' from my DataFrame with FeatureSelector I thought I was feeding the FunctionTransformer a pandas Series which should work with pd.qcut, e.g. pd.qcut(df['Fare'], q=5)

Comment: @LazyEval Replacing `['Fare']` with `'Fare'` in the `FeatureSelector` argument in the Pipeline will work in that way:  `X[['Fare']]` is a dataframe, but `X['Fare']` is a Series, which will work in `qcut`.  That works fine with your second simpler Pipeline, but will fail in the first because now `SimpleImputer` will complain about a 1D input.

Comment: Oh right OK, hadn't even really thought of the difference between X['Fare'] and X[['Fare']]... silly me. Thanks for that!

Comment: I'm not getting the same results with `quantile` `KBinsDiscretizer` and `pd.qcut` when applied to a simple 1D array (e.g. `np.random.rand(10,1)`). From what you are saying, both solution should be identical.

Comment: @m_power, the mathematical content is the same (although I could understand slight differences due to interpolation, I didn't find any in a random example such as yours), it's just the format that's different.  `KBinsDiscretizer`'s `bin_edges_` match `qcut`'s second optional output `bins` on a random example.  `qcut` returns the output as Intervals, while `KBinsDiscretizer` returns those encoded either as one-hot or ordinal.

Comment: @BenReiniger, In Colab, when I try `np.random.seed(0); data = np.random.rand(10,1);
ext = KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=3, encode='ordinal', strategy='quantile'); test1 = ext.fit_transform(data); test2 = pd.qcut(data[:,0], q=3, labels=False)`, I'm getting different bins for index 3 and 5.

Comment: @m_power, thanks so much for that!  It looks like the bin edges in both methods are nearly same, and always(?) data values.  `pd.qcut` sets "right" endpoints whereas `sklearn` uses `np.digitize` with default "left" endpoints.  So one would expect every bin endpoint to flip between adjacent bins between the two methods.  However, there are numerical precision issues as well, so that sporadically the two binning methods agree on endpoints.  (I'm still surprised that bin edges don't end up at midpoints or linearly-interpolated points between data points...)